# I keep getting an infinite loop when I choose a certain option in my program

Tags: c

i have this program that asks users to enter info stores it in file and allows u to edit entries or add new ones or delete ones by setting gross salary to 0.

However when i try to modify a name , it doesn't modify , and when i try to modify gender, it causes an infinite loop can any1 tell me whats wrong?

And i think there something wrong with my break statements i made within the loop , thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
  int employee_number;
  char employee_name[20];
  char employee_sex;
  int employee_gross_salary;

}information;
int main()
{//open main function
  information customer;
  int i;
  int choice;
  int number;
  int choice2;
  int number2;
  FILE *fptr = fopen("emp.dat", "wb+");

  //asking user to enter atleast 5 customers into datarecords
  for(i = 0; i<1;i++)
  {//open for
    printf("enter employee's number\n");
    scanf("%d",&customer.employee_number);
    getchar();
    printf("enter the employee's name\n");
    scanf("%s", customer.employee_name);
    getchar();
    printf("enter employee's gender\n");
    scanf("%d",&customer.employee_sex);
    getchar();
    printf("enter employee's salary\n");
    scanf("%d",&customer.employee_gross_salary);
    getchar();
    fwrite(&customer,sizeof(customer),1,fptr);
  }//close for 

  for(;;)
  {//open for
    printf("\n what would you like to do\n1]Add entry\n 2]Delete entry \n3]Modify     entry\n4]view entries\n5]exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if(choice == 5)
    {break;}
    else if(choice == 1)
    {//open else if
      fseek(fptr,0, SEEK_END);// check the parameters here
      printf("enter new employee's number\n");
      scanf("%d",&customer.employee_number);
      getchar();
      printf("enter the new employee's name\n");
      scanf("%s", customer.employee_name);
      getchar();
      printf("enter new employee's gender\n");
      scanf("%d",&customer.employee_sex);
      getchar();
      printf("enter new employee's salary\n");
      scanf("%d",&customer.employee_gross_salary);
      getchar();
      fwrite(&customer,sizeof(customer),1,fptr);
      continue;

    }//close else if
    else if( choice == 2)
    {//open else if
      printf("enter the employee number of person\n");
      scanf("%d",&number);
      fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
      while((fread(&customer,sizeof(customer), 1,fptr))!=NULL)
      {//open while

        if(customer.employee_number == number)
        {//open if
          customer.employee_gross_salary = 0;
        }//close if

      }//close while
      continue;
    }//clsoe else if
    else if(choice == 3)
    {//open else if
      printf("enter the employee number of the employee you would like to modify\n");
      scanf("%d",&number2);
      printf("what would you like to modify\n");
      scanf("%d", &choice2);
      fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
      while((fread(&customer, sizeof(customer),1,fptr))!= NULL)
      {//open while within else if
        //1 to midify name, 2 to modify gender 3 for salary
        if(customer.employee_number == number2)
        {//open if

          if(choice2 == 1)
          {

            printf("enter new name\n");
            scanf("%s",customer.employee_name );
            break;
          }
          else if(choice2 == 2)
          {
            printf("enter new gender");
            scanf("%d", &customer.employee_sex);
            break;  
          }
          else if(choice2 == 3)
          {
            printf("enter new gross salary\n");
            scanf("%d",    &customer.employee_gross_salary);
            break;
          }

        }//close if

      }//close while within else if
      continue;
    }//close else if
    else if(choice == 4)
    {
      fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_SET);
      while((fread(&customer,sizeof(customer),1,fptr))!= NULL)
        printf("\n%d\t%s\t%c\t%d\n",            customer.employee_number,customer.employee_name,customer.employee_sex,customer.employee_gro    ss_salary);
      continue;
    }
  }//close for
  return 0; 
}//close main function
```

Comment: The title burn my eyes, also the sms speaking

Comment: try to reproduce you problem with a small code. with this you will get your answer faster

Comment: You don't lk elt spk?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done some C , but I'm don't seem to recall anything like this : `for(;;)` . Quid ?

Comment: @nrathaus jst if itz not insd StkOvrfl0w

Comment: @Bartdude: It is a infinite loop, valid as I recall (I don t remember it being C++ only)

Comment: @Bartdude infinite loop - maybe that's the core problem ;)

Comment: why don't you debug your code by yourself? I think that is the way to solve this problem. and you should know how to debug

Comment: @user3051896: You are using infinite loop, continue and break as if they were cheap things, they are flow breaker, you should refactor your code to avoid using them, it should also make it easier to find your error

Comment: @SebastianDressler > I didn't even know (remember) such loop was possible. As far as I remember we were always using `while` to perform this kind of stuff, forcing a user input.

Comment: Duplicate of [scanf ignoring, infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285737/scanf-ignoring-infinite-loop) ?

Comment: @Bartdude yes, that is more common. But I've also seen kind of this stuff in benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT the answer for your debug, just some advice for refactoring your code and future writing:

1.
Avoid using break and continue, they are flow breaker, bug sources, bad and evil, it is the same for go to, they are here for specific no-other-way cases.

You can do something like:

```
int end = 0,
    choice = 0;

do
{
    fprintf(stdout, "1:Do stuff\n2:Do other stuff\n3: Do another stuff\nX: end\n");
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice) != 1){}
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        //Do other stuff
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        //Do another stuff
    }
    else
    {
        end = 1;
    }
}while(end == 0);
return 0;
```

No continue, no break, easier to modify, easier to write, easier to read, shorter, in two word: way better

2.
Write in english, always, you have a full keyboard and do not pay by letter, it is almost as fast to type the entire word, and help a lot other to understand.
Also, it will help you to make less error when you write text or code.

3.
You can declare multiple variable at once if they are of the same type:

```
int var1;
int var2;
int var3;
...
```

Is long and repetitive, instead you can write:

```
int var1,
    var2,
    var3;
```

A good habit can be to always initialize variables, it help prevent some bug:

```
int var1=0,
    var2=0,
    var3=0;
```

4.
Whenever you use a function, test its return, there is a lot of bug that happen from thinking "it is a stdio function, it is bug-proof". As exemple, your fopen of emp.dat. It can fail (and in fact will fail at some point).

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("emp.dat", "wb+");
if (fptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening emp.dat\n");
    return -1;
}
```

5.
If you are a begginner (there is no shame about that, everyone begin at some point, and we can say everyone is still begginning even after 10+years of coding), write your algorithm first, then code. Exemple:

```
//Get user's choice
//If user choice is do stuff
    //Do stuff
//If it is do other stuff
    //Do other stuff
//If it is do another stuff
    //Do another stuff
//Else if he want to quit
    //Quit
```

Which then become

```
int choice=0, //User's choice
    end=0; //End of program

do
{
    //Get user's choice
    fprintf(stdout, "1:Do stuff\n2:Do other stuff\n3: Do another stuff\nX: end\n");
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice) != 1){}
    //If user choice is do stuff
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    //If it is do other stuff
    else if(choice == 1)
    {
        //Do other stuff
    }
    //If it is do another stuff
    else if(choice == 1)
    {
        //Do another stuff
    }
    //Else if he want to quit
    else
    {
        //Quit
        end = 1;
    }
}while (end == 0);
return 0;
```

It also prevent you from going to comment your code weeks later when you don t know anymore why you did that or that stuff.

6.
Log, log, log, especially at debug!
You can put it on stderr if you want, so you can separate it from your output.
Exemple:

```
int end = 0,
    choice = 0;

fprintf(stderr, "Start\n");

do
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\tBegin loop\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "1:Do stuff\n2:Do other stuff\n3: Do another stuff\nX: end\n");
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice) != 1){}
    fprintf(stderr, "\tChoice is: %d\n", choice);
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tStarting do stuff\n");
        //Do stuff
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tEnding do stuff\n");
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tStarting do other stuff\n");
        //Do other stuff
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tEnding do other stuff\n");
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tStarting do another stuff\n");
        //Do another stuff
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tEnding do another stuff\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tEnd order\n");
        end = 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\tEnd of loop\n");
}while(end == 0);
fprintf(stderr, "End\n");
return 0;
```

So you know when and where is your program right now, it is a HUGE help for debug!

That s all I have in mind right now, hope it can help you.

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Edit:

Thanks to chunk, another important point:

7.Always checking scanf for valid user's input. User's input can and will be almost eveything, and will at some point not be what you think, test it, always. (it is not valid only for (f)scanf, but for EVERY ways you get your data from other sources but your own source code)

```
int check = 0;
fprintf(stderr, "\tBegin loop\n");
fprintf(stdout, "1:Do stuff\n2:Do other stuff\n3: Do another stuff\nX: end\n");
check = fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice);
if(check != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad input\n");
    return -1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "\tValid choice is: %d\n", choice);
```

This way, any other input but a decimal number will be discarded and will close the program, of course you can do it better.

```
int check = 0;
fprintf(stderr, "\tBegin loop\n");
fprintf(stdout, "1:Do stuff\n2:Do other stuff\n3: Do another stuff\nX: end\n");
while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad input!\n");
}
fprintf(stderr, "\tValid choice is: %d\n", choice);
```

In this version, when the user type something invalid, he just have to try again.

Comment: All these ideas, yet the result of `scanf()` is not checked - IMHO, the most important idea.  If user entered a good digit '1' to '3' and then entered 'X', this code would loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DrakaSAN's answer I would add that you should **always** flush the input buffer when you take *character/string* input after taking *integer* input.

One way to flush the input buffer is to use `getchar()`:

`while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n');`

But if the user gives the input as "123 abc\n" (as mentioned by *chux* in comment) assuming 123 goes to the integer variable and "abc" to the character array, then there are ways to resolve this:

```
//can be modified according to programmer's requirements
int a;
char arr[10],ch;

scanf("%d",&a);

while((ch=getchar())==' ' || ch=='\t' || ch=='\n') //loop until non-whitespace character
{
    if (ch=='\n')
    {
        ch=getchar();
        break;
    }
}

if (ch!='\n') //ch contains the first character of the character array
{
    arr[0]=ch;
    gets(arr+1);
}
else //if two consecutive new lines after integer, string contains nothing
    arr[0]='\0';
```

Comment: Performing a `fflush()` on an input stream like `stdin` results in UB.  Might work on select platforms, but is bad practice for portable code.  C11 7.21.5.2 2 The `fflush` function "If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I never said to use `fflush()`. There are ways to flush the input buffer. You can use `getchar()` after integer input to flush out the buffer.

Comment: I understand the idea of flushing `stdin` would be to discard all the data presently in `stdin`.  Maybe you have some definition that you could cite.  How would you handle redirected `stdin`?  How would you handle input "123 abc\n".  Since this answer says to **flush** and your comment "I never said to use fflush()", maybe you should post how it would be accomplished?

Comment: Please elaborate on the part "How would you handle input "123 abc\n"". Is "123 abc\n" the input to an integer variable or a character array?

Comment: Neither.  With code `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice)`, input `"123 abc\n"` should scan in the "123" and leave the `" abc\n"` for the next IO operation.  Taking of _integer_ input does not always imply that everything after the digits up to the `\n` should be discarded (flushed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the results when `choice == 2` and `choice == 3` before the `continue`, like

```
fseek(fptr, -sizeof(customer), SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&customer,sizeof(customer), 1, fptr);
```